# TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 32, 32) for image data - showing a colored image in plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have an array of images where each image is stored as the following dimension

> (3, 32, 32)

if I wanted to show an image using

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

then I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 32, 32) for image data

I understand why I am getting this error, because according to [imshow documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), it takes an array of shape

> (M, N), or (M, N, 3), or (M, N, 4)

How can I convert the image such that it has the required dimensions without losing any of its data?

Thanks!

Comment: you have (3,M,N) right? instead of (M,N,3)

Comment: @joostblack yes

Comment: Try transposing: `img.T`. This will reverse the order of the dimensions, making it `(M,N,3)`

Comment: @JussiNurminen Thanks! that worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try transposing: `img.T` This will reverse the order of the dimensions, making it `(M,N,3)`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem with using `img.T` is that the images will change their orientation.
the best alternative is to use `img.permute(1, 2, 0)`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'permute'

Answer (score 7):

you can put the channel dim to the end

```
img = img.swapaxes(0,1)
img = img.swapaxes(1,2)
```